# Saving file to s3 while decompressing

Tags: linux, amazon-s3, split, gzip

I am using the following command to download the file from s3 and zip it into smaller zips.

```
aws s3 cp "${INFILE}" - | gunzip | split -b 1000m --filter "gzip > ./logs/cdn/2021-04-14/\$FILE.gz | echo \"\$FILE.gz\""
```

This is working fine on local and saving the file in local.
I am not sure how to upload this file directly to s3 without saving in local after smaller zips are generated.

Comment: If i am not getting the question wrong, then you want to process the file on local machine and upload it directly without saving,right, so if that is the case then what you can do is to save the file parts locally once the upload to s3 is completed, you delete the file parts from local machine. Am i right or you want something else?

Comment: I don't want to save the part file. it should be directly uploaded to s3 using pipe.